# Is it possible to setup a single node HDP without Ambari?

Tags: hadoop, centos, ambari

I'm trying to setup a single node HDP installation in my virtual machine running a CentOS 7 operating system.

Is it possible to set it up without Ambari? Or is it a hard prerequisite? I'm looking to install HDP 3.1.

Thanks!

Comment: You can directly download virtual box from https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/hortonworks-sandbox.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run HDP without Ambari and Hadoop has documentation covering [single node installations](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html).

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried the setup using Ambari, and it's so convenient versus the old-school way.

Comment: That documentation is just Hadoop and YARN, not HDP versions of it

Comment: @tk421, would it still be possible to manage your cluster via Ambari if it was installed the manual way?

Comment: You can save off your config settings then reapply them inside Ambari.